# Updating multiple values of different keys in map using java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have converted a JSON file to a map and I need to modify multiple values of different keys at once using JAVA.

Following is the map converted JSON file:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "numberID": null,
    "StartDate": "",
    "EndDate": "",
    "count": null,
    "level": null,
    "discipline": null,
    "paymentModel": null,
    "ownerName" : null,
    "coursepackType": null,
    "note": null
}
```

I need to update multiple values at once from above JSON, I want to add value to following keys:

- name
- StartDate
- EndDate
- count
- ownerName

All I have write now is way to update just single value, which is already pretty linear: 
Using following series of functions:

```
String body="";
File testDataJsonfile = new File("path/xxx.json");
        JsonNode testJSONNodes = getJsonNodes(testDataJsonfile);
        Map<String, Object> mapWithJSONNodes = convertJSONTOMAP(testJSONNodes);
        body = updateValue(mapWithJSONNodes, "name", "abc")

public String updateValue(Map<String,Object> map ,String key,String value) throws JsonProcessingException{
            map.put(key, value);
            String convertedJSONFile = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
            return convertedJSONFile;
        }
```

Any way to to achieve what I want dynamically, probably passing an array list or so?
Please let me know if any other specification is required.

Comment: Map has a putAll method...

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the method to accept another `Map` rather than key value pairs and update the existing `map` with new values present in another `map`, e.g.

```
public String updateValue(Map<String,Object> map, Map<String, String> updatedValues) throws JsonProcessingException{
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>(map);
    resultMap.putAll(updatedValues);
    String convertedJSONFile = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(resultMap);
    return convertedJSONFile;
}
```

You can call this method with `Map`, e.g.:

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("name", "abc");
values.put("foo", "bar");
body = updateValue(mapWithJSONNodes, "name", "abc")
```

Also, rather than modifying the map passed in the request you should create a new map and return it (to maintain the state of existing `map`).

Answer (score 0):

Most of this code should only be executed once - the parsing of the `json` file into a `Map` and the serialization of the updated `Map` into a `JSON` `String`.

Only the `put` statements should be repeated for each key/value pair you wish to add or modify:

```
File testDataJsonfile = new File("path/xxx.json");
JsonNode testJSONNodes = getJsonNodes(testDataJsonfile);
Map<String, Object> mapWithJSONNodes = convertJSONTOMAP(testJSONNodes);
mapWithJSONNodes.put ("name", "abc");
mapWithJSONNodes.put (...);
...
String body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(mapWithJSONNodes);
```

If you have some array or `List` containing the keys and values you wish to add, you can replace the `put` statements with a loop, to reduce the code a bit further.